# Special unicode string splitting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, emoji, unicode-string

I am working with emoJ in javascript. I want to do something look like on the site http://www.emojiselector.com

For example, I have a message in unicode emoj:    ️
How can I split every characters, I mean , , , , , ...

I just want to use javascript based libraries for client side: jquery, dojo... (**not nodejs**).
I tried to process as normal string, but I didn't get success. I wonder that some unicode characters are not 1 space, but can be 2, 3,... spaces and some unicode characters is not shift left to right, but is right to left. So the index of normal string can not be done.

Anyone can help me please !

Comment: did you try using split? I don't have much experience with unicode, but `'  '.split('')` works just fine... if it doesn't, could you provide the code you have so far?

Comment: For example:
s = "  ";
    document.write(s.split('')); The result will be: 
�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�, ,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�, ,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�,�

Comment: Might try `str = [...s]` but works only in ES6

Comment: I need a method well works in almost popular browsers !I never use ES. AND THE MOST IMPORTANCE IS NOT USE NODEJS, I just want to pure js for client or js framework for client only!

Comment: *I wonder that some unicode characters are not 1 space, but can be 2, 3,... * https://eev.ee/blog/2015/09/12/dark-corners-of-unicode/#javascript-has-no-string-type

Comment: I knew this, but this is nodejs. I need a pure js lib for client side only !!!!